# how to display content in html table format in Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

trying to display 2 items which will be added by **bAddItem()** below side by side in the output.I tried using HTML tags but couldn't succeed, I also used writing HTML tags in response.write() but failed,can anyone suggest how to display the text and checkboxes side by side in output

```
<%  
for iCount = 0 to UBound(aPhoneTypeId,2) - 1
dim Consentindarray
dim Checkedstatus
dim consentvalue
Consentindarray=""
Checkedstatus=0
Consentindarray = split(TrimValue(oRstInd("user48")),",") 
for each consentvalue in Consentindarray
   if InStr(1, consentvalue, trim(aPhoneTypeId(0,iCount)) ) > 0 then
        Checkedstatus=1              
   end if
next
if Len(trim(aPhone(iCount))) > 0 then
   if aPhoneTypeId(0,icount) = sPhoneType then 
       **if bSuccess then bSuccess = bAddItem(oSectionNode, "text", aPhoneTypeId(1,icount), aPhone(iCount), "", true)**  end if

       **if bSuccess then bSuccess = bAddItem(oSectionNode, "checkbox","",Checkedstatus, "", false)** end if

   else 
     if bSuccess then bSuccess = bAddItem(oSectionNode, "text", aPhoneTypeId(1,icount), aPhone(iCount), "", false) end if

     if bSuccess then bSuccess = bAddItem(oSectionNode, "checkbox","",Checkedstatus, "", false) end if

   end if
  end if
next
```

Comment: How does the method 'bAddItem()' look like?

Comment: Show the code that tries to write the HTML tags...

Comment: When you tried Response.Write to output HTML tags, did you remember to use TWO sets of double quotes for your attributes.  eg Response.Write("<input type=""hidden"" name=""inputname""/>")

Comment: The code snippet you provided doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. At minimum, we need the code of the "bAddItem" function.

Answer (score 1):

You output a table the same way as you would any other html: either with `Response.Write` statements, or by turning off scripting with `%>` and then writing actual html.

```
 <html>
 <head><title>This is my page</title>
 <%
 dim V, N, i
 %>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
 <%
 ' ... (code to load data into V() goes here)
 ' ...
 If N = 0 Then 
    Response.Write "<tr><td colspan='2'>No data found</td></tr>"
 Else
    For i = 0 to N-1
       Response.Write "<tr><td>" & V(0,i) & "</td><td>" & V(1,i) & "</td></tr>"
    Next
 End If
 %>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

<sub>I took the "easy way out" for quoted values: I simply used single quotes, because html doesn't care either way. If you must have double quotes, your options are to double your double quotes (`"<td colspan=""2"">"`) or use character codes: (`"<td colspan=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & ">"`).</sub>

That said, it doesn't look like you're outputting anything that's tabular. From what little I can make out, it looks like you're trying to write out a checkbox and a label. The mechanics of that aren't any really any different; you just need to use the appropriate html tags. (One thing though: it's almost always better to have the checkbox first, then the label — that's what most people are used to, and if you have a list of checkboxes, they'll align much better that way.)

```
...
<form method="post" action="FormName.asp">
<input type="hidden" name="Option1" value="<%=Opt1%>">
<%
For f = 1 to iCount
   Response.Write "<p><label><input type='checkbox'"
   Response.Write " value='" & aPhoneTypeId(0,f) & "'"
   Response.Write " name='PhoneType_" & f & "'"
   If aPhoneTypeId(0,f) = sPhoneType Then Response.Write " checked"
   Response.Write ">" & aPhoneTypeId(1,f) & "</label></p>"
Next
%>
</form>
...
```

(Note that I have no clue what your variables actually contain, so the above is probably utter gibberish, but it should give you a hint about how to get started.)